# Unable to create reachable host-name site collection in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint

These are the commands i ran Administrator Windows Power Shell to create a host-name site collection to a existing web application

1. `powershell -version 2`
2. `Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell`
3. `New-SPSite http://www.test5.sp/ -OwnerAlias MyDomain\administrator -HostHeaderWebApplication http://Mywebapplication/`

In this point i see a new site collection created under `Mywebapplication` in central admin.

I added a new record to hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1  test5.sp
```

And i get ping for `test5.sp`

I edited the bindings of iis and added a new binding:

```
Type|Host Name|Port|Ip Address
http|test5.sp |80  |127.0.0.1
```

And then ran

```
iisreset /noforce
```

In this point the `test5.sp` is not accessible from the browser.
Can you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to access the host name site collection that i created after the following changes:

1. I changed the iis bindings to be:

> ```
> Type|Host Name|Port|Ip Address
> http|test5.sp |80  |*
> ```

2. For some reason (that i don't really understand) there is a problem to access the host name site collection from a machine that the SharePoint is installed on.
   So i added the test5.sp to the host files on another machine:

> ```
> [The ip address of the webapplication] test5.sp
> ```

This solved the problem :)